# Redirect docroot for specific URI path by .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, httpd

Is it possible to redirect a specific URI path to a specific `docroot` within the original `docroot` using the `.htaccess`?

For example:

```
example.com > docroot
```

Where

```
example.com/path > docroot/subdir
```

Comment: Sorry, really not sure what you are getting at here? What problem are you trying to solve?  Describe in natural language what it is you are trying to do and what your current config consists of.

Comment: I think I understand the question, and have the same one myself. One example problem is that ErrorDocument requires a docroot-relative pathname for an error handler, like "/error.php". Being able to change the doc root to the subdirctory in which the htaccess file exists would make "/error.php" refer to an "error.php" located in the same directory as .htacess instead of one located in the document root. I suspect that the answer is "NO", that this is another limitation of the Apache directives: the doc root is a constant.